# Comparing a php variable and mysql table element that has backslashes

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create an online database of the music I locally have on my computer.  I already have a table of every song in my library and would like to create a different table with just the song ID's (auto-incremented when I added the songs to my main table) that act as one of my playlists.

From what I can tell, the only 100% certifiable method for matching the songs is by the location on my disk ( C:\Users\username\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Music\Jonathan Coulton and GLaDOS\Portal\128 128 Still Alive Duet.mp3 ) as an example.  In my PHP code I get the song location into a variable and if I print it relative to the equivalent song location in my MYSql table, they match up exactly but when I try to run a select statement using that, it gives me an error.  From what I can tell this is being caused by the backslashes in the location info.

This is the select statement I'm using,

```
SELECT id FROM itunes WHERE Location=$locationval
```

where $locationval is the current song's location, id is the autoincremented id in my main table, and itunes is my main table.

Is there any way around this?  And as I am a beginner, is the backslashes really the issue?

For reference here is the full code for importing the playlist, its using the DB plugin for PEAR (a PHP extension).

```
<?php

// define table name
define('TABLE_NAME', 'playlist');

// create database connection
require_once('DB.php');
$dsn = 'mysql://username:password@localhost/itunes';
$DB =& DB::connect($dsn);
if (DB::isError($DB)) {
  die($DB->getMessage());
}
$DB->setFetchMode(DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);

// load text file
$file = file_get_contents('Portal.txt');

// explode on new line
$file = explode("\r", $file);
set_time_limit(0);


// loop through each line in the file
foreach ($file as $key => $value) {

  // explode on tab to get column list
  $exploded = explode("\t", $value);

  // check for first row, which contains column headers
  if ($key == 0) {

 }
   else{

    if(count($exploded)>3)
    {
    $locationval=$exploded[26];
  echo $exploded[26];
  echo "<br />";
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM itunes WHERE Location=$locationval");
  //$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM itunes WHERE id=8292");
set_time_limit(0);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
  //test statements to see if the query worked
  echo "Test: ";
  echo $row['id'];
  echo $row['Location'];    
  echo "<br />";

  }
  }

}
?>
```

Which was modified from the code here: http://ericlondon.com/posts/208-exporting-itunes-data-into-mysql-and-creating-sql-to-show-top-rated-albums

If any more info is needed, please let me know.

Comment: If `$locationval` is your path, you need to surround it by quotes after escaping like `'".mysql_real_escape_string($locationval)."'` in your query.

Comment: If @air4x's suggestion doesn't solve your problem, I'd suggest posting a couple of sample rows from your table (returned by `SELECT * FROM itunes LIMIT 5`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes when using it in mysql as a string literal, so just replace your following line:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM itunes WHERE Location=$locationval");
```

for this one:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM itunes WHERE Location='". str_replace('\\','\\\\',$locationval) . "'");
```

that should do what you want.

Comment: That worked like a charm.  Thank you very much.  I'm glad I was right that it was the backslashes causing the issues.  Cheers.